# How can I delete single URL search auto complete entry in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, history, autocomplete

I use Chrome by typing directly into the URL text box to search for things. I program in C# and one day I made the awful mistake of pressing <kbd>/</kbd> instead of <kbd>shift</kbd> and the search became “C/#.” From that day on out most of my searches are “C/# blah blah blah’ which is invalid because of the / so I have to go back and edit it.

This *cannot* be removed by doing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> for some reason, unlike many other auto completed URLs. The icon for it is different as well. It looks like a new file icon.

I am using Windows. I do not want to remove all of my history.

Comment: Go to CTRL+H and look in the history..  Can you delete from there?  if that does not do it..  Go to Google and look in your search history and delete from there.

Comment: I tried both. Two entries showed up and I deleted them but that's all that showed up. I think that history list only shows to a certain amount of time and does not let you adjust it.